# How to use multithread in Swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, swift2

I have two tasks : task1 and task2. I want to execute task2 after task1 finishes.

```
let globalQueueDefault = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)

dispatch_sync(globalQueueDefault){

self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = false
self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

    task1()

    sleep(6)
    dispatch_sync(globalQueueDefault) { () -> Void in

        task2()                                             
    }
}
```

I searched in internet, I find `NSLock`,`NSConditionLock` and `objc_sync_enter`...I have try them, but it doesn't work...

```
let lock = NSLock()
let globalQueueDefault = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)

dispatch_sync(globalQueueDefault){

self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = false

self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating() 

self.lock.lock()

task1()
self.lock.unlock()

sleep(6)
dispatch_sync(globalQueueDefault) { () -> Void in
self.lock.lock()
    task2() 
self.lock.unlock()                                            
}
}
```

I also tried `NSConditionLock` and `objc_sync_enter`...It doesn't work. How I can use `lock` in swift ? Could you give me a example base on my code? Thank you.

PS: I don't want to use `callback` here...because I have tried it, I think multithread is more closer to my answer, Thank you.

Comment: Where are the multiple threads? What are task 1 & 2? Why aren't you using a serial queue?

Comment: I am sorry, perhaps I used a wrong word "multiple threads", `task1()` is download json, and `Task2` pass to  another View. I think you have understood my question and what I want ? Could you tell me how to use `lock` in my code ? Thank you very much

Comment: You should not use locks, you should use a callback...

Comment: But `task1()` download jason from internet, I do not know when It finish...I used `callback`, and `task2()` cannot wait `task1()` finish...

Comment: The callback is sent when task 1 completes and it runs task 2

Comment: Thank you very much, could you give me a example?

Comment: I can not use `lock` here? why?

Comment: "The callback is sent when task 1 completes" what is meaning of completes? callback can know I have get json from internet or not ? or callback works just those lines codes without check if I have success get json or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going out on a limp and making some guesses about your program structures. The first problem with your code is that it's trying to access a view on a background thread. GUI elements should always be accessed on the main thread. The second problem is `sleep`: don't use it to write concurrent code. It makes assumptions about how the asynchronous task is going take. You should treat that time as unknown and use a sync pattern or a call back.

Since you mentioned that `task1()` download JSON, it's likely asynchronous. Here's how I'd do it:

```
func task1(finish: () -> Void) {
    // Set up your connection to the website
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        // Handle the response, parse the json, etc
        ...

        // Now call the completion handler
        finish()
    }
}

func task2() {
    // Do whatever here
}

// In the function that triggers the JSON download
func downloadJSON() {
    self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = false
    self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    task1(task2)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have fond a solution, but I think your answer for callback is right, so I support you. Thank you very much